# Perl variable disambiguation within regex

Tags: regex, perl, variables, disambiguation

I want to ensure variables are interpolated as they are within perl regular expressions. Would rather avoid binding over to other variables in a cascate of "ifs" that would rarely need that variable throughout the code execution. How could I ensure I used the variable?

```
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => "all";

$_="botherther";

my $bo = "bother";
if (/^$bother$/) { # want to consider just $bo here!
  print("Undestood regex as /($bo)ther/.\n");
} else {
  print("Couldnt discern variable.\n");
}

my $bi = { bo => "the" };
if (/^bo$bi->{bo}[r]ther$/) { # now, $bi->{bo} only
  print("Discerned /bo($bi->{bo})[r]/\n");
} else {
  print("Couldnt discern variable.\n");
}
```

I'm not able to find a way to wrap the variables properly within the regex. Of course I could just `my $bi_resolved = $bi->{bo}` or fill the regex with null-thingies (like `[]` or `()`), but this does not feel like a proper separator.

For clarity:

1. I wanted to expand `$bo` into `bother` to get the `/botherther/` string in the first match.
2. I wanted to expand `$bi->{bo}` into `the` to get `<bo><the><[r]ther>`, again `/botherther/` in the second match.
3. Important noting, I don't care for the sake of this context, about the escapes `\Q` and `\E`, *"I am assuming there's never metacharacters within the variables"*.

I have searched thru questions, read documentation, and couldn't find an answer for this. Wrapping in `${}` didn't work for me (that's trying to dereference stuff). So, while searching I feel I am just barking at the wrong tree... It's simply unbelievable nobody ever needed to ask something like that around perlmonks or stackoverflow. I'm probably just looking for the wrong keywords here. :/

Comment: For `/^$bother$/` I could make do with `/^${bo}ther$/`. But for `$bi->{bo}`, just `${bi->{bo}}` (i.e. wrapping in `${}`) doesn't do, errors with _"Can't use bareword ("bi") as a HASH ref"_.

Comment: That's because `$BLOCK[...]` is an array lookup, where `BLOCK` is expected to return a reference to an array

Comment: where am I using `$BLOCK[...]` in my code?.. I know I could use something like `(?{ code })` (re-eval code), but to me it would be too overkill, and having a temporary simpler variable would be better. **re-eval** code would be great for a very complex match I won't require to do a lot of times in a program, I guess.

Comment: Re "*where am I using $BLOCK[...] in my code?*", You didn't show it, but you said you tried `/^bo${bi->{bo}}[r]ther$/` ("*Wrapping in `${}` didn't work for me*")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To separate interpolated variable names from other text is usually
done like `${name}`

So, a part of the code sample becomes

```
use strict;
use warnings;

$_="botherther";

my $bo = "bother";
if (/^${bo}ther$/) { # want to consider just $bo here!
  print("Undestood regex as /${bo}ther/.\n");
} else {
  print("Couldnt discern variable.\n");
}
```

A good way to test stuff is to put it into a `qr//` then print it out :

```
my $rx = qr/^${bo}ther$/;
print $rx;
```

---

Per @choroba :

As far as the regex goes, it looks like the variable can also be wrapped
in a  group without modification and should cover all cases.
It's really just a parsing thing. If Perl can distinquish delimiters to get
a variable notation in a string, it will interpolate it.

Like `(?:$bo)` or `(?:$bi->{bo})`
but it will be wrapped inside a residual group.

Comment: what about the `$bi->{bo}` bit (which shouldn't consider the `[r]` bit)?

Comment: A hash reference ? Probably want to assign it to a `my $bo = $bi->{bo};` bit. Keep dereferencing it untill you get a scalar.

Comment: `/^bo(?:$bi->{bo})[r]ther$/`

Comment: As far as the regex goes, it looks like the variable can be wrapped in a group without modification and should cover all cases. Like `(?:$bo)` or `(?:$bi->{bo})` but it will be wrapped inside a residual group..

Comment: About the `$bo = $bi->{bo}` I mentioned in the question I had reasons it wasn't desirable in my case (look up `$bi_resolved` in the question). The untracked-grouping might be the way to go and fulfill my needs. Wouldn't it be reasonable if @choroba nailed the answer here?

Comment: The important thing is to learn; who earns the XP is insignificant :)

Comment: instead of a non-capturing group, you can \-escape the -. or add an empty comment `(?#)`

Comment: @ysth, I wanted to consider the dereferencing in that case, I wanted to use `$bi->{bo}` and keep as regex the `[r]` bit (which could be something like `[rR]` to make more sense). The point was, it could be undestand by perl as a continuation of the variable, as an array index refernce `$bi->{bo}[r]` (which would result in a syntax error, in the example).

Answer (score 2):

There are four main ways:

- Use `/x` (`$bi{bo} [r]` instead of `$bi{bo}[r]`)
- Use curlies around the variable name (`${bo}ther` instead of `$bother`)
- Escape the next character (`$bo\->[0]` instead of `$bo->[0]`)
- Isolation via parens or some other means (`(?:$bi{bo})[r]` instead of `$bi{bo}[r]`)<sup>[1]</sup>

That said, if you're interpolating text (rather than a regex pattern), you should be using `\Q$var\E` anyway, making the problem moot.

```
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => "all";

$_="botherther";

my $bo = "bother";
if (/^\Q$bo\Ether$/) { # want to consider just $bo here!
  print("Understood regex as /^botherther\$/.\n");
} else {
  print("Couldn't discern variable.\n");
}

my $bi = { bo => "the" };
if (/^bo\Q$bi->{bo}\E[r]ther$/) { # now, $bi->{bo} only
  print("Discerned /^bothe[r]ther\$/\n");
} else {
  print("Couldn't discern variable.\n");
}
```

Thanks to @ysth for improvements.

---

1. Imposes a small run-time penalty.

Comment: I may want to interpret the variable, so I emphasized in my item (3) that I was not looking for a \Q \E solution. Sorry if I made a long question and you didn't feel like reading it all. Here's what I posted: _"Important noting, I don't care for the sake of this context, about the escapes \Q and \E, "I am assuming there's never metacharacters within the variables"."_. Your first suggestion drops the `->` of the variable, I was looking for a way to arbitrarily wrap the variable name, which the curly brackets didn't do. Anyways, thanks for the collaboration.

Comment: Re "*I am assuming there's never metacharacters within the variables*", That's a stupid assumption to make. There's no reason to open yourself up to code injection bugs/attacks just to avoid `\Q...\E`, especially when the alternative (`(?:...)`) is just one character shorter.

Comment: I meant for the sake of my question, this very important and relevant fact is not taken into account...... I already know what the `\Q` and `\E` does and their application is not the point of the question....